# Binding C++ member variable : getter/setter or raw pointer?

Tags: c++, binding

I'm currently trying to design a property system, to bind member variables of a few classes to a serializer, and I want to write the least possible code for each binding, and yet be flexible.

I think getters/setters aren't really necessary most of the time, so they would only be used when they actually trigger something. The classes would provide a list of variable names, and either a pointer to the variable, either a pointer to getters/setters.

My questions are :

- Is binding by pointer actually dangerous or even moral?
- Can these classes give these pointers without knowing their actual instance? (ie get binding info once for all instances of each class, and store that somewhere). AFAIK, Boost::bind doesn't allow that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dangerous yes, immoral no.  You can make the classes be friends of the serializer and hide the binding stuff for mortals to improve safety, then you have a set of related classes which are morally allowed to know about each others internal structure.

The class can definitely return the binding info, for instance as byte offsets.  It may be easiest though if the class owns a "prototype" object of that class (i.e. static member of its own type).  Then by getting the address of a prototype field as a `const char *` and subtracting from the address of the prototype also as a `const char *` you get the byte offset for the field.

Of course, then you need to make sure you know what type the field is, so you can correctly manipulate the data given a byte offset (e.g. cast back to the correct pointer type).

However there are many gotchas around implementing something like this, which mostly revolve around making sure you have the correct pointer type when serializing, rather than a pointer to some subobject within the object.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using boost::property_map

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/property_map/doc/property_map.html